# How to filter a subquery?

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

This is based on [AdventureWorks sample database.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=ssms)

And here is my query:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName,

(SELECT COUNT(SalesOrderID)
FROM SalesOrderHeader
WHERE SalesOrderHeader.ContactID = Contact.ContactID) AS OrderCount

FROM Contact
ORDER BY OrderCount desc
```

Question: what should I add to my query so it only shows OrderCount that is more than 20? Nothing else should change about my output. I tried this and it did not work:

```
WHERE SalesOrderHeader.ContactID = Contact.ContactID AS OrderCount AND COUNT(SalesOrderID) > 20
```

Comment: Hint:  `HAVING`.

Comment: Where should I put it exactly?

Comment: Since [tag:adventureworks] is specifically geared to SQL Server, I've added the tag as such. If this isn't the case please edit the tag to the correct RDBMS.

Comment: It goes after the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite as a join aggregation query and then use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT
    c.FirstName,
    c.LastName,
    COUNT(s.SalesOrderID) AD OrderCount
FROM Contacts c
INNER JOIN SalesOrderHeader s
    ON c.ContactID = s.ContactID
GROUP BY
    c.FirstName,
    c.LastName
HAVING
    COUNT(s.SalesOrderID) > 20;
```